# rails links_to helper with html block

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb, link-to

I have a rails 4.2 app. I would like to have the whole `tr` to be clickable and take the user to the user to the product show page.

At the moment the html gets rendered without `<href..` and I don't exactly understand why. What did I miss?

index.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody class="product-profile-index">
      <%= render @products %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

_product.html.erb (partial for index page)

```
<%= link_to product do %>
  <tr class = "product-index-row">
    <td class="col-md-3 name">
      <span class="product-image">
        <%= image_tag attachment_url(product, :product_image, :fill, 45, 45) %>
      </span>
      <span class="product-name">
        <%= product.name %>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-6 oneliner">
      <%= product.oneliner %>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-3 updated">
      <%= local_time_ago(product.updated_at) %>
    </td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

css.scss

```
.product-profile-index {
  .product-index-row {
    &:hover {
      background-color: $gray-medium-light;
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

If I wrap just a smaller part of html like this, then it's working:

```
<%=link_to product %>
  <%= product.name%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you add `<%= product_path(@product) %>` somewhere on the page and let us know what it outputs?

Comment: It's working. I used to have it with `<%=link_to product %><%= product.name%><% end %>` and worked fine. (I only put the instance variable in my question to make it easier to read, but that can't be the issue)

Comment: Excellent. Can you add it so we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
<tr class = "product-index-row" data-href"/product/<%=@product.id%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not DRY but working pretty well.

I had to pass the link into each `td` like this:

```
.......
<td>
<%= link_to(product, html_options = {style:"display:block;"}) do %>
......
<% end %>
</td>
..........
```